# Duplicate entry '78161' for key 'PRIMARY' (Sendo que não está duplicado)

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Tenho uma tabela que guarda os dados das pessoas e quando dou um insert pra adicionar um novo registro ele diz que o 'id' (chave primaria) está duplicado, entretanto não está duplicado.

A tabela em que estou inserindo os dados é

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `registration` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pis` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `senha` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `barras` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cpf` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rg` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailAcesso` varchar(2000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salt` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admin` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `inativo` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `contingency` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `endereco` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `bairro` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cep` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cargo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `admissao` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `telefone` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ramal` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pai` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mae` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nascimento` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sexo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `estadoCivil` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nacionalidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `naturalidade` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idResponsavel` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `responsavelNome` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `veiculo_marca` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `veiculo_modelo` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `veiculo_cor` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `veiculo_placa` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dateLimit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `visitorCompany` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `blackList` bit(1) NOT NULL,
  `dateStartLimit` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `pisAnterior` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `comments` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `wtech_integracao` varchar(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Quando for integrar só funcionara quando este campo for  “S”, quando for null não será possível a alteração, exclusão e inclusão.',
  `deleted` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `idDevice` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `allowParkingSpotCompany` bit(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idArea` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dataLastLog` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeOfRegistration` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `objectGuid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_users_contingency` (`contingency`),
  KEY `idx_users_idArea` (`idArea`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=78163 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

O insert que estou dando é esse (nem coloco o id ai, pq como é auto increment o banco calcula sozinho)

```
insert into controlid_teste3.users (name, registration, inativo, pis, senha, admin, contingency, idType, blacklist, pisanterior, wtech_integracao) values ('ABDON COSTA FILHO', '9299', 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,'S')
```

O problema é que toda vez que dou o insert ele diz que a chave primeira ta duplicada

```
Duplicate entry '78161' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

ai eu executo o insert novamente e ele vai pro proximo valor da chave

```
Duplicate entry '78162' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Sendo que nenhum desses valores existem na tabela, se eu ficar tentando enviar o insert tem uma hora que ele é inserindo, então não estou entendo o que está gerando esse problema.
obs: esse é um banco de dados que é gerado por um programa ( idsecure, da empresa controlid)